# Quickdb add Is not a function error with Quick.db

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

Tried making a warning system by following a tutorial on youtube, guess it was outdated because I get this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: db.add is not a function
```

Here is how the code works.

```
const db = require('quickdb')
const member = message.member
        const user = message.mentions.members.first()
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
if (reason) {

            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Warning')
                .setColor('GREEN')
                .setDescription(`${user.user.username} Was Warned For ${reason} By ${member.user.username}`)
                .setFooter(`Bot by Yaay#6969`);

                user.send(`You have been warned in **${message.guild.name}** for ${reason} By ${member.user.username}`)

                db.add('userInfo.warningsnumber', 1)
                db.push('userInfo.warnings', `${reason}`)
                db.get('userInfo.warningsnumber')
                db.get('userInfo.warnings')

            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to require it like this

```
 const db = require('quick.db');
```

I think you have a typo here

```
const db = require('quickdb') //TYPO it's quick.db not quickdb
```